# Vue.js2 - Child component is not being rendered

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm new to vuejs and just started playing with it. While trying different tutorials I'm stuck at this code sample which is not working. Can anyone please explain why the **second-component** is not being rendered?

```js
Vue.component('first-component', {
  template: `<div>This is first component: {{val}}!</div>`,
  data: function () {
    return {
      val: "FIRST <second-component></second-component>"
    }
  },
})

Vue.component('second-component', {
  template: `<p>This is second component: {{val}}</p>`,
  data: function () {
    return {
      val: 'SECOND'
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <first-component></first-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have put the `<second-component>` in the val variable, and trying to render it with Mustache syntax However as stated in [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)  *The double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not HTML*

You can use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) to insert the component as plain HTML but again it is [stated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html): *the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates.*

The only way you can render `second-component` is by putting this in the template:

```
template: `<div>This is first component: {{val}}!<second-component></second-component></div>`,
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the statement __"Note that the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates."__ This is the reason why it does not get rendered. And I think it really should be that way.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are returning it as "data" in "val". So that's not evaluated to a component. If you put it in the template, it works.

```js
Vue.component('first-component', {
  template: `<div>This is first component: {{val}}! <second-component></second-component></div>`,
  data: function () {
    return {
      val: "FIRST"
    }
  },
})

Vue.component('second-component', {
  template: `<p>This is second component: {{val}}</p>`,
  data: function () {
    return {
      val: 'SECOND'
    }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#example'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="example">
  <first-component></first-component>
</div>
```